# List of all products and their ingredients

Tags: data-request, food

I need list of all products with following attributes,

- Ingredients
- Country or origin
- Manufacturer

Now the tricky part is that, I don't want it for JUST a specific country, I want it around the globe and I don't mind automating this task too as I am a software developer.

However I don't want to reinvent the wheel which is why asking here is my first approach. I don't mind and I think the only choice would be to gather data from supermarkets somehow ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Open food facts](https://world.openfoodfacts.org/) is a "*food products database made by everyone, for everyone*". And "*it is open data, anyone can re-use it for any purpose*".

It has calories, ingredients, photos. It's crowdsourced : you can use it and contribute to it as well (and let your user contribute) according to the OdBL licence.

Comment: We're building an open crowdsourced database for food products. We have calories, ingredients, photos. You can use it and contribute to it as well (and let your user contribute) according to the OdBL licence :-)  https://world.openfoodfacts.org