# API either database on organic/natural products

Tags: food

While databases and API offerings around nutrition, foods and recipes are flourishing, I fail to find a machine readable data source for **organic/natural products** as food without relationship to the related products you can actually buy.

With nutrition data, I mean not only the typical triple "carbs, protein , fats" but the complete list of nutrients like vitamins and minerals and what not being important for human well being.

Comment: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/11027/1511 ??

Comment: Open Food Facts focuses on packed/processed foods with a barcode; they do have categories for say "fresh vegetables" but then you will not find all minerals.

Comment: more like this https://fdc.nal.usda.gov/ ?

Comment: @philshem yes, thank you! this looks much better even if the search is not really bijective.